# Как вернуть проект на состояние нескольких коммитов назад?

Tags: github

Всем привет. Гитхабом всегда пользовался исключительно для хранения своих проектов там, скачивания их на новые устройства и тд. Но тут возникла проблема. Я внес много изменений, закоммитил их, а по итогу понял, что лучше проекту быть без них. И вот как вернуться на несколько (!) коммитов назад я не понимаю. "Вернуться" - это буквально откатить все изменения в файлах, вернуть удаленные, удалить появившиеся и тд. Просто вернуться.

Как это сделать, используя Github Desktop?

Comment: `git revert <commit-SHA>` буквально отменит все изменения от HEAD до указанного комита. В истории появятся комиты отменяющие комиты. Все файлы вернутся в состояние "как было до".

Comment: Работать надо в рабочих бранчах. Тогда если бранч не удачный, его просто бросают и открывают новый бранч. Если бранч удачный его мержат в основной бранч. Новая фича - новый бранч. Новый багфикс - новый бранч. Иногда бывает несколько рабочих бранчей одновременно.

Answer (score -2):

Зайди в проект и сверху где число коммитов, нажми на него, тебе покажет где ты его редачил и выбери тот на который хочешь вернуться и browse files сверху.

Делай это из браузера, без понятия че там в клиенте гитхаба, но через команды reflog.